# Inserting PHP into HTML in Javascript block

Tags: javascript, php, html, yii2

Confusing title, but accurate, sorry. I have a page that shows an Html::submitButton. Now I want this button to be shown only when all checkboxes on the page are checked. For this I added a javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(document.getElementById("checkbox").checked = true){
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = `
            <div class="parent">
                <?php Html::submitButton('Finish Process', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger', 'id' => 'finish']) ?>
            </div>
      `     ;

          }
</script>
```

The html button is from the framework and I believe it needs to be coded in PHP. Since this is in an HTML block in a Javascript block, I have no idea how to insert this properly. How do I have to change this code?

Comment: The fact that this is wrapped in JS doesn't really matter here, especially since you're using a template literal; you are composing an HTML string in a `.php` document. Anyway, you're creating a div and setting its `.innerHTML` but then you're discarding it. You need to append the newly created div somewhere for it to display.

Comment: why dont you simply show and hide the button ? why complicating things by inserting the content in this way, and how are you going to make sure that your check runs at the time when all the checkboxes are selected , currently it does not look like so

Comment: and add the checkbox list that you are using to check all the checkboxes, is it a `checkboxList` ? or multiple different checkboxes ?

Comment: Also I believe you miss echo there.
<?php Html::submitButton() ?> should be <?php echo Html::submitButton ?>